# Using clang_complete with OS X frameworks

Tags: macos, vim, clang, clang-complete

If I save the following to /tmp/test.cpp:

```
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  CFStringRef my_string = CFSTR("hello, world!");
  std::cout << CFStringGetLength(my_string) << '\n';
}
```

I can compile this correctly with `!clang++ -framework CoreServices %`, however clang_complete can't complete anything from CoreServices.

The docs say I should place compiler options in a .clang_complete file (in this case I'm using /tmp/.clang_complete), however everything I've tried so far results in `test.cpp|| unknown argument: '-framework'` appearing in the quick fix window.

What's the correct way of getting clang_complete to deal with frameworks correctly?

Comment: VIM try to search clang_complete from you cwd no? Then if you're not in /tmp/ your file must not be in /tmp/ !

Comment: cwd is /tmp/ - I know the .clang_complete file is being read because of the 'unknown argument' error only appearing when I add the `-framework` option to .clang_complete.

Comment: You mean to call clang_complete using :!clang++ ? But this only call the compiler! Is your clang_complete this plugin : http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302 ?

Comment: I know that calls the compiler :) I've got clang_complete working fine, just not with frameworks. It is that plugin although I'm using the latest version from https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete

Comment: I am having the same issue with the -arch flag. I can compile my project with clang from the command line, but clang_complete complains of unknown argument:'-arch'.  I had a look through the source and although I'm not familiar with python, all the useroptions arguments seem to get cleanly passed through to libclang.dylib (to the function clang_parseTranslationUnit). That's as far as I've got now- I posted an issue on the project page. Will keep you updated if I make progress.

Comment: If anybody knows how to test whether libclang.dylib supports certain arguments, that could rule it out (or not).

Answer (score 0):

See [clang_complete: Vim autocompletion for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840791/clang-complete-vim-autocompletion-for-ios/7859661#7859661) for a helpful answer. Apparently `clang_complete` uses the `-cc1` option which doesn't support the `-framework` argument.

I was able to use `-triple` and `-target` options as replacements for the `-arch` argument I needed, maybe one of the `-cc1` args can replace `-framework`?

To reproduce your error, you can do

```
:! clang -cc1 % -framework CoreServices
```

So I think the question now becomes "How can I pass frameworks to `clang -cc1`?".

EDIT: By running

```
clang++ -v -framework CoreServices ./test.cpp
```

You can get the output of `clang -cc1`

Mine was

`-triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.6.7 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name test.cpp -pic-level 1 -mdisable-fp-elim -relaxed-aliasing -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 123.2 -v -resource-dir /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/../lib/clang/2.1 -fdeprecated-macro -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 179 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/w2/w26NavGvGauuJwhTtEeQ9++++TI/-Tmp-/cc-GbJXd6.o -x c++ ./test.cpp`

I removed the -o argument, and the input file, from the end and added it to the user options in `.vimrc` but code completion still doesn't work correctly.. Hmm

Comment: Thank's for your contribution :) If no other answers you get the bounty soon ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone also still has this problem (I'm having it with the spacemacs extensions to `company-clang`, but I expect the issue is the same)...

The `clang -framework` argument is apparently passed to the linker, while `clang -cc1` is concerned exclusively with compiling (so it doesn't know about or support linker options; it does accept a `linker-option=<option>` argument, apparently, which worked for me in my shell, but was unrecognized when added to the `.clang_complete` file).  A framework is basically just a bunch of nested collections of headers, though, so you can just include all the headers you need in the framework manually with `-I` and it will work.

Example for Qt5:

Instead of...

```
-F/usr/local/opt/qt5/lib
-framework QtCore
```

Use...

```
-I/usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
```

I guess you may have to do some introspection of the headers in your particular framework to figure out exactly which directories to include.  Could be a lot of them.  Not very pretty, but it works (in my case, at least).