# clang_complete: Vim autocompletion for iOS

Tags: ios, vim, clang, clang-complete

So recently I have been trying to set up a Vim-based iOS workflow.

I found clang_complete, and have set the clang user options in my .vimrc like so

```
let g:clang_user_options='-fblocks -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40300'
```

as described here: http://www.zenskg.net/wordpress/?p=199#comment-229

and added a few framework/header/lib paths. I'm not going to post the whole line because it is huge.

So I tested the compilation of one of the files in my project using `clang` from the command line (using the same options), and it compiles fine, but *only* if I use the `-arch armv6/7` flag. If I don't it tries to compile for i386 and complains of missing header files.

So far so good. Now I just use the exact same options I gave to `clang`, to `clang_complete`'s user options in my `.vimrc` right?

Nope. When I do that and try to autocomplete a word in Vim, it says

```
 unknown argument: '-arch'
```

in the QuickFix list of Vim. I kinda need this flag- how should I proceed?

Any ideas useful. I would love to get iOS code completion working under Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clang_complete runs `clang -cc1`, which causes the compiler front-end to run and not the driver. The compiler front-end doesn't understand the `-arch` option. `clang -cc1 --help` will show you the possible options. You should probably specify `-triple` or one of `-target-*`.

If you're not sure what to use, you can run clang manually as you did, but in verbose mode (`-v`). This way it will print the `clang -cc1` command line, where you can find the appropriate arguments.

Comment: Thanks so much... This got me a lot further. I ran xcodebuild with in verbose mode, copied the clang options, then ran clang with these options in verbose mode, then copied the clang -cc1 options from the output into my .vimrc.  clang_complete still can't autocomplete my code though, I think I need to use the -frameworks flag which doesn't seem to have an equivalent in -cc1. Could you point me to some documentation? The man pages are not very good- I would never have known about the -cc1 option without you telling me.

Comment: Here's something you could try: open ~/.vim/plugin/clang_complete.vim (or wherever you have installed clang_complete), and look for the ClangCompleteBinary function. There are two things you could try there:

1. Comment out the v:shell_error condition block. Clang will often returns good completion options even when it had a compilation error, and clang_complete ignores this fact.

2. change system(l:command) to system(l:command . '|& tee /tmp/clang.log') and trigger a completion from vim. Then you'll be able to see in /tmp/clang.log the exact error output from clang.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

By default, clang_complete is using the clang binary `/usr/bin/clang`, but Xcode isn't. It's using the clang library `/Developer/usr/clang-ide/lib/libclang.dylib`. They're not quite the same. If you're copying the options that XCode is using, you'll have to make sure clang_complete uses the library version too.

Something like this in your .vimrc file should do it:

```
filetype on
autocmd FileType objc let g:clang_use_library=1
autocmd FileType objc let g:clang_library_path='/Developer/usr/clang-ide/lib'
```

When I do that, `-arch i386` is accepted.

(PS - I had a couple of other problems getting clang_complete to work for iOS development. You *might* want to check out this fork: https://github.com/krisajenkins/clang_complete. I'm too new to clang to really know what I'm doing, but it's working for me...)

Answer (score 0):

Using the 5.1 sdk I wasn't able to get -arch accepted even when using libclang.dylib.

After some futzing (namely, manually running the clang commands produced by xcodebuild with the `-v` flag as suggested), my best setup was:

```
let g:clang_complete_auto = 1

"not strictly necessary
set omnifunc=ClangComplete

let g:clang_user_options='clang -cc1 -triple i386-apple-macosx10.6.7 -target-cpu yonah -target-linker-version 128.2 -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.1 -fblocks -x objective-c -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -D __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 || exit 0'
```

adding `-cc1` is the only thing I don't see mentioned in other resources on Stackoverflow or elsewhere (apparently this flag allows the bastardized combination of clang driver and raw cc1 flags to go through). Once this was added it suddenly just worked at least for Cocoa and UIKit completion (try typing `[NSString C-x C-u`).

However, something's still mildly busted.

Typing `:copen` I see this after a completion (successful or otherwise):

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFURL.h|654 col 48 error| expected ';' after top level declarator

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFUtilities.h|14 col 39 error| expected function body after function declarator
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h|60 col 32 info| expanded from macro 'CF_AVAILABLE_IOS'
/usr/include/Availability.h|145 col 53 info| expanded from macro '__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING'
<scratch space>|25 col 1 info| expanded from macro '__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h|92 col 10 error| 'CoreFoundation/CFUserNotification.h' file not found
```

Also, even though I've added various `-I` flags to either my `.clang_complete` file or directly to the `clang_user_option`s string, `clang_complete` only works with some but not all of the headers in my project... with no apparent reason why one works but not others. (Suggestions welcome).